# Map list by partial function vs lambda

Tags: python

I was wondering whether for most examples it is more 'pythonic' to use [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) or the [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function?

For example, I might want to apply [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) on some list, like add 3 to every element using:

```
imap(lambda x : x + 3, my_list)
```

Or to use [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
imap(partial(operator.add, 3), my_list)
```

I realize in this example a loop could probably accomplish it easier, but I'm thinking about more non-trivial examples.

*In Haskell, I would easily choose partial application in the above example, but I'm not sure for Python. To me, the lambda seems the the better choice, but I don't know what the prevailing choice is for most python programmers.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To be truly equivalent to `imap`, use a generator expression:

```
(x + 3 for x in mylist)
```

Like `imap`, this doesn't immediately construct an entire new list, but instead computes elements of the resulting sequence on-demand (and is thus much more efficient than a list comprehension if you're chaining the result into another iteration).

If you're curious about where `partial` would be a better option than `lambda` in the real world, it tends to be when you're dealing with variable numbers of arguments:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def a(*args):
...     return sum(args)
... 
>>> b = partial(a, 2, 3)
>>> b(6, 7, 8)
26
```

The equivalent version using `lambda` would be...

```
>>> b = lambda *args: a(2, 3, *args)
>>> b(6, 7, 8)
26
```

which is slightly less concise - but `lambda` does give you the option of out-of-order application, which `partial` does not:

```
>>> def a(x, y, z):
...    return x + y - z
...
>>> b = lambda m, n: a(m, 1, n)
>>> b(2, 5)
-2
```

Comment: I can have my list comprehension and a generator? Python seems to have everything :-p Thanks.

Comment: out-of-order arguments are the best argument I ever heard in "lambda vs partial". To be fair though, `partial`s are faster than lambdas - just for the rare case where that matters.

Answer (score 5):

In the given example, lambda seems most appropriate. It's also easier on the eyes.

I have never seen the use of partial functions in the wild.

Comment: upvoted for use of "in the wild"-- in the jungle with the pythons right?

Answer (score 4):

lambda is certainly many times more common. Unless you're doing functional programming in an academic setting, you should probably steer away from functools.

This is pythonic. No library needed, or even builtins, just a simple generator expression.

```
( x + 3 for x in my_list )
```

This creates a generator, similar to imap. 
If you're going to make a list out of it anyway, use a list comprehension instead:

```
[ x + 3 for x in my_list ]
```

Comment: This solution does create a second list, it does not add 3 to items in a list.

Comment: Er, why steer away from `itertools`? There are many useful things in it for everyday programs... do you mean `functools`?

Comment: @Amber: certainly list comprehension is cleaner than imap? I've never encountered a need for itertools, but that's a different question...

Comment: this is absolutely the pythonic way to do it, and probably the fastest as well.

Comment: `imap` and a list comprehension do different things: the former creates a generator; the latter creates a full list. Now, if you were to refer to *generator expressions* as opposed to list comprehensions, you would be closer to correct.

Comment: list comprehensions are on of my favorite python tricks. also don't forget using parentheses instead of brackets for generator expressions, which are more optimal if you're planning to just iterate through it again later.

Comment: I don't know how I missed seeing that Python has list-comprehensions! Thanks for answering my question and providing the more pythonic alternative.

Comment: Generators are incredibly more efficient when performing chains of operations on large lists.

Comment: The particular strength of `imap` is that it can easily take multiple iterables without having to first zip them together into tuples for a comprehension.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; list comprehensions aren't equivalent to imap at all.  Again, you want a generator expression.

Comment: @pst @Glenn Maynard: I've edited the post to address your concerns.